# Mostrar um número especifo de casas decimais em números com ponto flutuante na linguagem Lua

Tags: c++, lua, ponto-flutuante

Comecei a aprender um pouco sobre a linguagem Lua e estou fazendo alguns algoritmos para praticar e um deles devo mostrar na saída dos valores de ponto flutuante com 4 casas decimais. Em C++ eu usaria `cout << fixed << setprecision(4);`, procurei muito e não encontrei uma maneira na linguagem Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa de forma semelhante ao [`printf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) da linguagem C:

```
string.format("%.4f", 25.33333333)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/eoTS7Y). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qzsjkubf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/Format.lua).

[Essa página pode ajudar](http://lua-users.org/wiki/FormattingNumbers).

[Documentação básica](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.html).

Comment: Isso mesmo, deu certo. Muito obrigado! =]